# How to resolve undefined Input Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

There is input data in component:

```
  @Input() pupil: Pupil;
```

Before rendering this data in template I need to map it:

```
 ngOnChanges() {
    this.pupil.photo = Helper.getPhoto(this.pupil);
  }
```

But I get error cause `this.pupil` in undefined, but after I can see filled object.

How to await result from Input?

In template I have `*ngIf="pupil"`

Comment: Can you provide the parent template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It' normal the you have the error. Try this:

```
ngOnChanges() {
if(this.pupil!=null){
    this.pupil.photo = Helper.getPhoto(this.pupil);
}
  }
```

Comment: But it looks awful, could I use life circle angular?

Comment: yqah! th eproblem is that sometimes ngonChanges is called when  these value is null! is it work? pls give me correct answer?